# How to use Live Visual Tree on WPF window within a WinForms application?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I have a Win Forms project which contains a WPF window within an ElementHost.  I'd like to use the Live Visual Tree to debug the WPF UI, but when I run the application, the tree is completely empty.

I am guessing this is because VS sees I am running a Windows Forms project and doesn't know to hook the tree up to the WPF portion of the project.

Is there a way to do this, or does the startup project have to be a WPF app for the tree to work?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: I don't think this is supported in this version of VS. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/100844/xaml-edit-and-continue-not-working-if-wpf-control.html. The app should be WPF for Live Visual Tree to work.

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks like you're right to me.  If you'd like to post that as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VS does not support Live Visual Tree for Winform apps even if it has WPF controls embedded.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/100844/xaml-edit-and-continue-not-working-if-wpf-control.html

Comment: Looks like there are no plans to support it. There's always Snoop [https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf] which works well in mixed Forms/WPF apps.

Comment: I also can confirm that VS 2019 continues not supporting it. A great tool, as mentioned by @Ryan_S is Snoop. I am using it. Don't know if there are other similar alternatives.